# Sequential calculations in Pandas using last calculated value

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone suggest a way to apply a function sequentially, so not only using the last calculated value of the column being computed but also using the present and past values of other columns in a pandas dataframe.

To illustrate my use case, lets say I have the following dataframe with "Start" and "End" markers for a event and i need to mark the occurrence of the event with "1" in a new column called "Event". 
Description of the columns:

- ***Start***: Marked as 1 when the conditions are such that lead to start of event, if there is 1 in this column then it would either indicate starting of the event or that the already existing event would continue even if the End column has a 2.
- ***End***: Marked as 2 when conditions are such that lead to end of event if the Start column is 0, if start is 1 the values do not have any impact on the running event.
- ***Event***: This column needs to be calculated such that we mark 1 for those rows where the event is running.

The logic in the example is that I start event with 1 and end it either at overlapping 1 and 2 or at the very next two as soon as the 1s end.

```
    Start   End   Event
1   0       0     0
2   1       2     1
3   1       2     1
4   0       0     0
5   0       0     0
6   0       0     0
7   1       0     1
8   0       2     1
9   0       2     0
10  0       0     0
```

I understand that if I can find a way to implement a function sequentially using values of other columns from the present row I can easily use their past values using .shift(...) on those columns. So far, I have found a python implementation of sequential calculation but only on the same column here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pydata/0MCWhwurOWs
and the python code here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4567

I have never used cython and am wondering if it is possible to implement it using the above.

Essentially, what I find lacking in pandas is the simple kind of calculation where i can not only refer to the values of the other columns but also the calculated values of the same column to do the calculations for the current rows. This is difficult since pandas is column based and applies the column based array functions.

I would really appreciate help on this.

Comment: This is very unclear. In what way do "Start" and "End" columns mark an event? Spell it out to us. Anyway it sounds like "Event" needs to be a vectorized logical-or of `diff(df$Start) & diff(df$End)`. But we can't know until you explain Start, End columns.

Comment: @smci: Thanks for responding, I have added clarification as asked for. The crux of what I am trying to do is to be able to apply a function such that it has access to current values of all columns and past calculated values of the current column.

Comment: *Event* is a logical, not an integer, and frankly *Start, End* sound like they might be too. Makes it clearer to keep them logical.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well even after the clarifications, your question is still poorly-defined, the example you gave breaks your own definition since the event starting on line 2 never ends, since neither line 3 nor 4 satisfy your end condition as currently stated: ("If Start==1 the value End==2 does not have any impact on the running event(?!)")

But here's an outline solution for you to tweak, you can figure the rest out:

- The tools you want are `diff` and `cumsum`. You also need to do some boolean calculations.
- `diff()` will give you both positive and negative diffs; since you're only interested in the earliest positive change, then compare the output of `diff(...) == +1`
- Here we compute two intermediate vectors event_started, event_ended, then cast them to integers so we can do a cumulative-sum `cumsum(as.integer(event_started) - as.integer(event_ended))` which seems roughly what you want:

.

```
df <- data.frame(Start=c(0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0), End=c(0,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,0))

event_started <- c(F, diff(df$Start)) == +1
FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
event_ended   <- c(F, diff(df$End==2) == +1) & !event_started
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

cumsum(as.integer(event_started) - as.integer(event_ended))
0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1

df$Event <- cumsum(as.integer(event_started) - as.integer(event_ended))
```